# What are these mounts for on inside edge of carbon fiber fork?

Tags: fork, carbon, compatibility, accessories, fenders

I just got a new [Tommaso Sterrata](https://giantnerd.com/collections/tri-cross-tt/products/2015-tommaso-sterrata-disc).

I commute during the winter so I'm looking to put fenders on. I know I can get fenders that clip onto the fork instead of being mounted, but while inspecting the fork, I found these two screws on the inside edge of the fork.

What are they for? What are they supposed to do, and what *can I do* with them. Would it be feasible to mount the fender stays on them?

[image: screws on inside edge of fork]

Comment: It's plausible that they're intended for fenders.  I wouldn't think anyone would put a rack on a carbon fork.

Comment: fenders are about all i could guess, especially sense they advertise it for gravel and cross use. If it were setup for the new direct mount brakes they would be on the front. (i realize it's obviously a disc frame)

Comment: The Specialized Diverge line have [carbon fiber forks with low rider mounts for racks](http://forums.roadbikereview.com/specialized/specialized-road-questions-318671-10.html#post4685234).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They're for full fenders. Many disc road and fitness/urban/hybrid bikes now have them here in order to completely avoid strut interference with the brake. To install the fenders neatly I've been mounting the fender, then mounting the struts sticking off into space in the general direction they'll run in from the mount, then bending one with a non-marring plier or adjustable wrench in each hand to get the strut pointing straight into the eyebolt of the fender, and then bending the other to match.

Answer (score 9):

Tommaso here.

We put them on the fork so riders can install fenders for off road and other adverse weather situations.  Hope you enjoy the new Sterrata!

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Thank you for making it clear that you are representing the company.   I look forward to your inputs on other questions too, will be interesting to see the POV from a manufacturer rather than a rider.

Comment: Have rolled back to revision 2 because revision 3 failed in it's stated objective, it achieved the opposite effect